# MS-Access Report Total

Tags: ms-access, report

Having difficulty displaying group totals on an Access report.
The completion % totals by department are correct but the overall percentage is not correct.
The overall is showing 92.6% when it should be 93.6%

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would have to directly analyze data and queries which you have not provided. I suspect a rounding issue.

Comment: Is there a way to add the values of percentComp in the DepartmentDesc Header and display the total in the Report Footer?

Comment: You can Sum() the field just as you are using Avg().

Comment: Do this test. Have 3 textboxes in footer to do calcs with Sum(IIf()) expression for each of the 3 group items. `Round(Sum(IIf(DepartmentDesc='Transportation',PercentComp,Null)),1)`. Now have expression in 4th textbox to add the 3 controls and divide by 3. Do you get correct result?